# What is the definition of an "objective kill"?

Tags: terminology, overwatch

At the end of a match, the game lists off a number of statistics for my performance, including "eliminations" and "objective kills."  The second number is usually (always?) smaller than the first.

Based on the in-game scoring notifications, an elimination happens when you do damage to a player who then dies, even if you did very little damage or did not perform the killing blow yourself.  But what is an objective kill?

I imagine they are related to ["objective time."](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266813/what-is-objective-time)  Objective kills probably means something like "the number of players you killed who were contesting the objective," but I'm curious about the precise rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on experience you get an Objective Kill when you kill (or damage) an enemy player while he is on or near the objective.

Meaning that on payload maps an enemy player would need to be actively pushing or contesting the payload.

Same goes for point captures, where, to get an objective kill, an enemy would need to be on the point that is to capture or to defend.

This also means that you cannot get more Objective Kills than normal Kills.

Comment: How about killing an enemy while *you're* on the objective, but they aren't? That's the only condition left unmentioned. Other than that, great answer :)

Comment: @KizTrap The only way to answer that would probably be to SCIENCE! it in a Custom Game...

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Not necissarily but I could try it in about 6 hours, if noone has done it by then.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, you get Objective Kills when getting an elimination while standing on/next to the objective as well as if you help eliminate someone on the objective. Basically, it is an indication of how much you were fighting over the objective, whether defending it, attacking it, or pushing it.